# HTML/CSS - Footer won't push to bottom & Image failing to align correctly

Tags: html, css

My Website URL: http://cudahost.com/new

Hello,

My footer is floating in the middle of the page, it doesn't push to the bottom below all content where it's suppose to be, can somebody help me with this please? I've spent hours googling and found nothing, I've tried several code changes too.

The other issue is the home boxes, the feature boxes, as you can see the top line of features has a picture of a cloud, and looks messy, I am trying to align that picture to the top right, preferably on the same line as the titles (Control Panel, Powerful Hardware, Server Mod Support) so they each have an icon on them, but not bothering the description too much. So basically, Title Here                Image Here
Title on left, image on right, obviously both on the same line, but doesn't matter if the image goes down a little, but not effect the descriptions too much.

My CSS is:

```
body {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: #555;
    background-image:url('images/bg.png');
}


#navtopstick {
    background: inherit;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}

/* BASIC RESET */
ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,body,html,p,blockquote,fieldset,input{margin:0; padding:0;}

/* HTML ELEMENTS */
h1 { font-family:"Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif; text-align: center; color: #000; font-size:60px; letter-spacing:-1px; }
h1 small{ font-size: 24px; display: block; color: #636363; }

/* COMMON CLASSES */
.break { clear:both; }

/* WRAPPER */
#wrapper { width:980px; }

/* CONTENT */
#content { }
#content p { font: 14px "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif; color:#333333; line-height:18px; margin:15px auto; width:800px; }
#content p a { color:#0088CC; text-decoration:none; }
#content p a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }

/* STYLE NAVIGATION MENU */
#appleNav { list-style:none;

    /* Lucinda Grande is the font used */
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; letter-spacing:-0.5px; font-size:13px;

    /* Apply a subtle text-shadow to the text */
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 3px #202020;

    width:980px; height:34px;

    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #cecece;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #cecece;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px #8b8b8b;
}

#FooterWrapper {
    width: 100%;    
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: auto;
    bottom:0;
} 

#footerwrapper{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top:20px;
}

#footer {
    background: url(images/darker.png);
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    bottom:0;
} 

    .footer-links h3{ font-size: 20px; color: #36429B; margin-bottom: 10px; text-transform: none; font-weight: bold; }
    .footer-links a{ color: #484646; margin-bottom: 10px; text-transform: none; font-weight: bold; }
    .footer-links ul { list-style: none outside none; padding: 9px 0 0 0;  float:left; display:inline;}
    .footer-links:link { color: #484646; text-decoration: none}
    .footer-links a:visited { color: #484646; text-decoration: none}
    .footer-links a:hover { color: #7dc33a; text-decoration: underline}
    .footer-links ul li { float: left; display: inline; height: 20px; border-right: 1px solid #1a1a1a; padding-right: 10px; margin-right: 10px; }
    .footer-links ul li.last { border: 0; } 
    .footer-links ul li a { float: left; display: inline;  height: 20px; line-height: 20px; }

    .left, .alignleft { float: left; display: inline; }
    .right, .alignright { float: right; display: inline; }
    .topright, .aligntopright { float: right; float: top; display: inline; }

    .footerFloat h3{ font-size: 20px; color: #36429B; margin-bottom: 10px; text-transform: none; font-weight: bold; }
    .footerFloat a{ color: #7dc33a; margin-bottom: 10px; text-transform: none; font-weight: bold; }
    .footerFloat a:link { color: #7dc33a; text-decoration: none}
    .footerFloat a:visited { color: #7dc33a; text-decoration: none}
    .footerFloat a:hover { color: #7dc33a; text-decoration: underline}
    .footerFloatLast h3{ font-size: 20px; color: #36429B; margin-bottom: 10px; text-transform: none; font-weight: bold; }

.footerFloatLogo {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    min-width:200px;
    bottom:0;
}

.footerFloat {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    min-width:200px;
    bottom:0;
}

.footerFloatLast {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    min-width:200px;
    bottom:0;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
} 

#appleNav li { display:block; float:left; border-right:1px solid #5d5d5d; border-left:1px solid #929292; width:105px; height:34px; border-bottom:1px solid #575757; border-top:1px solid #797979;

    /* Gradient backgrounds for the buttons. Generated using http://gradients.glrzad.com/ */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #787878), color-stop(0.5, #5E5E5E), color-stop(0.51, #707070), color-stop(1, #838383));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #787878 0%, #5E5E5E 50%, #707070 51%, #838383 100%);
    background-color:#5f5f5f; /* Fallback */
}

/* Set the states when hovering */
#appleNav li:not(:last-child):hover {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #3F3F3F), color-stop(0.5, #383838), color-stop(0.51, #434343), color-stop(1, #555555));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #3F3F3F 0%, #383838 50%, #434343 51%, #555555 100% );
    background-color:#383838; /* Fallback */

    /* We use the inset of the box shadow to create a subtle inner glow when hovering */
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #535353;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #535353;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #535353;
}

/* When the user clicks the button, */
#appleNav li:not(:last-child):active {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #3F3F3F), color-stop(0.5, #383838), color-stop(0.51, #434343), color-stop(1, #555555));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #3F3F3F 0%, #383838 50%, #434343 51%, #555555 100% );
    background-color:#383838; /* Fallback */

    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 2px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 2px #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 2px #000;
}

#appleNav li a { color:white; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; display:block; line-height:34px; outline:none; }

/* Styling of the search field */
#appleNav form input { width:76px; height:20px; margin-left:9px; margin-top:8px; border:none; padding-left:20px; padding-right:10px; color:#eee;

    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;

    /* CSS3 multiple backgrounds for the input field: The magnifier image and the gradient background */    
    background-image: url("../images/magnifier.png"), -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #747474), color-stop(0.5, #6E6E6E), color-stop(0.51, #7E7E7E), color-stop(1, #8D8D8D));
    background-image: url("../images/magnifier.png"), -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #747474 0%, #6E6E6E 50%, #7E7E7E 51%, #8D8D8D 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-color:#6E6E6E; /* Fallback */

    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px 1px #363636;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px 1px #363636;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px 1px #363636;
}

/* Rounded corner for the first in last item. Shorthand: Top left, Top right, Bottom right, Bottom left. */
#appleNav li:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
    border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;

    border-left:none;
}

#appleNav li:first-child a img {
   vertical-align:middle; margin-top:-2px;
}

#appleNav li:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius:0 4px 4px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 4px 4px 0;
    border-radius:0 4px 4px 0;

    border-right:none;
    width:124px;
}

/* Fade in animation (Webkit only) */
@-webkit-keyframes showMenu {
    from { opacity: 0; top:-20px; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

#appleNav {
     -webkit-animation: showMenu 1s;
}

/* Features Area */
.box { background-repeat: repeat-y; background-position: 0 0; }
.box .box-b { background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0 bottom; }
.box .box-t { background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0 top; }
.home-box .box-b { background-image: url(images/nnnnnn.png);}
.home-box .box-t { background-image: url(images/nnnnnn.png); padding: 10px 20px; }
.home-box h4 { font-size: 16px; color: #36429B; font-weight: bold; text-transform: none; }
.home-box a { color: #1a8f1d; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 5px; display: block; }
.home-box img.right { margin-top: 50px; }
.cl { display: block; height: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; clear: both; }
.home-box {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 314px;
  background-image: url(images/darker.png);
  border:1px solid;
  border-radius:5px;
border-color: transparent;
  margin-right: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 19px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

And my index file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head><title>Cheap Minecraft Server Hosting - US/AU/UK | CudaHost</title>

<!--Meta Data -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="CudaHost | Cheap Minecraft Server Hosting - US/AU/UK"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="CudaHost | Cheap Minecraft Server Hosting - US/AU/UK"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Minecraft Server Hosting, Rapidly Responsive, affordable and reliable. No lag, Great Support! Supporting Bukkit,Spigot,Tekkit,FTB and more! Locatated; US/AU/UK"/>
<!-- <meta property="og:image" content="http://cudahost.com/fbthumbnail.png"> -->
<meta property="og:url" content="http://CudaHost.com">
<meta property="og:type" content="minecraft"/>
<meta name="description" content="Minecraft Server Hosting, Rapidly Responsive, affordable and reliable. No lag, Great Support! Supporting Bukkit,Spigot,Tekkit,FTB and more! Locatated; US/AU/UK">
<!-- End, Meta Data --> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="css/images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<?php flush(); ?> 
<body>
<!-- start header -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
<?php

include("header.html");

?>
            </div></div>
<!-- end header -->
<!-- Attempt Slider -->






<!-- home boxes -->
<div class="box home-box">
<div class="box-b">
<div class="box-t">
<h4>Control Panel</h4>
<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />
<p>We use an ultra-sleak, clean control panel that is rarely used by other companies, it's fast and extremely easy to use, full of brand new features!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div>
<div class="box home-box">
<div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Powerful Hardware</h4> <img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />
<p>Using powerful machines, nothing is a match for our hardware and we can provide you with fast and responsive customs at all times!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div>
<!-- second line -->
<div class="box home-box last">
<div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Server Mod Support</h4> <img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />
<p><b>We support almost every server mod including Tekkit, Bukkit, Hexxit and much more. Need help installing them? Submit a ticket!</b></p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div> <br />
<div class="box home-box"> <div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Specialized Support</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>We have a professional support team who are always happy to help, and are fast and caring about what they do. You can rely on us!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="box home-box"> <div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Migration Assistance</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>If you have a server elsewhere and want to move to us, we'll help you transfer all your files and data, apsolutely free of charge!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="box home-box last">
<div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Hardware Specs</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>E3-1270v3<br />32GB DDR3 ECC Memory<br />240GB Solid-State Drives<br />1Gbps Uplink</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div>
<!-- end home boxes -->

<!-- home boxes -->
<div class="box home-box">
<div class="box-b">
<div class="box-t"> 
<h4>Control Panel</h4>
<!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>We use an ultra-sleak, clean control panel that is rarely used by other companies, it's fast and extremely easy to use, full of brand new features!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div>
<div class="box home-box">
<div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Powerful Hardware</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>Using powerful machines, nothing is a match for our hardware and we can provide you with fast and responsive customs at all times!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div>
<!-- second line -->
<div class="box home-box last">
<div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Server Mod Support</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p><b>We support almost every server mod including Tekkit, Bukkit, Hexxit and much more. Need help installing them? Submit a ticket!</b></p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div> <br />
<div class="box home-box"> <div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Specialized Support</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>We have a professional support team who are always happy to help, and are fast and caring about what they do. You can rely on us!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="box home-box"> <div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Migration Assistance</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>If you have a server elsewhere and want to move to us, we'll help you transfer all your files and data, apsolutely free of charge!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="box home-box last">
<div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Hardware Specs</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>E3-1270v3<br />32GB DDR3 ECC Memory<br />240GB Solid-State Drives<br />1Gbps Uplink</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div>
<!-- end home boxes -->

<!-- home boxes -->
<div class="box home-box">
<div class="box-b">
<div class="box-t"> 
<h4>Control Panel</h4>
<!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>We use an ultra-sleak, clean control panel that is rarely used by other companies, it's fast and extremely easy to use, full of brand new features!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div>
<div class="box home-box">
<div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Powerful Hardware</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>Using powerful machines, nothing is a match for our hardware and we can provide you with fast and responsive customs at all times!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div>
<!-- second line -->
<div class="box home-box last">
<div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Server Mod Support</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p><b>We support almost every server mod including Tekkit, Bukkit, Hexxit and much more. Need help installing them? Submit a ticket!</b></p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div> <br />
<div class="box home-box"> <div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Specialized Support</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>We have a professional support team who are always happy to help, and are fast and caring about what they do. You can rely on us!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="box home-box"> <div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Migration Assistance</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>If you have a server elsewhere and want to move to us, we'll help you transfer all your files and data, apsolutely free of charge!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="box home-box last">
<div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Hardware Specs</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>E3-1270v3<br />32GB DDR3 ECC Memory<br />240GB Solid-State Drives<br />1Gbps Uplink</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div>
<!-- end home boxes -->

<!-- home boxes -->
<div class="box home-box">
<div class="box-b">
<div class="box-t"> 
<h4>Control Panel</h4>
<!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>We use an ultra-sleak, clean control panel that is rarely used by other companies, it's fast and extremely easy to use, full of brand new features!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div>
<div class="box home-box">
<div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Powerful Hardware</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>Using powerful machines, nothing is a match for our hardware and we can provide you with fast and responsive customs at all times!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div>
<!-- second line -->
<div class="box home-box last">
<div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Server Mod Support</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p><b>We support almost every server mod including Tekkit, Bukkit, Hexxit and much more. Need help installing them? Submit a ticket!</b></p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div> <br />
<div class="box home-box"> <div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Specialized Support</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>We have a professional support team who are always happy to help, and are fast and caring about what they do. You can rely on us!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="box home-box"> <div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Migration Assistance</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>If you have a server elsewhere and want to move to us, we'll help you transfer all your files and data, apsolutely free of charge!</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="box home-box last">
<div class="box-b"> <div class="box-t">
<h4>Hardware Specs</h4> <!--<img src="http://cudahost.com/new/icon.png" alt="" class="right" />-->
<p>E3-1270v3<br />32GB DDR3 ECC Memory<br />240GB Solid-State Drives<br />1Gbps Uplink</p>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div>
<!-- end home boxes -->

</div></div></div></div>
<!-- start footer -->
<br /> <br /> <br />
<div id="footerwrapper">
<div id="footer">
<?php

include("footer.html");

?>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end footer -->
</body></html>
```

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Removing `position: absolute` from your `#footerwrapper` pushes it to the bottom.

Comment: You could use a negative `margin-top` to align the clouds better

Answer (score 1):

## footerwrapper {

bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change absolute to relative;

```
#footerwrapper {
   position: relative;
}
```

Clouds:

```
.box-b {
   position: relative;
}
.home-box img.right {
   position: absolute;
   right: 5px;
   top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: On your site, those cloud images already has .right class. <img class="right"; not div.